# How do I transform a string from EditText to a character array, to allow audio implementation?

Tags: java, android, arrays, string

This is my code:

```
package com.example.pembroke.finalalgorhythmic;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {


Button asdf;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    asdf = (Button) findViewById(R.id.keybutton);
    asdf.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);


}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    EditText keyInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.key);
    String notes = keyInput.getText().toString();

}
```

What I want to do, is create a character array, so that I can use media player class to play certain sounds based on the user input after my button is clicked. Any ideas?

Comment: [`String.toCharArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray--)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried

`notes.toCharArray()` yet?

EDIT: Long version

EDIT 2: Sample implementation

```
MediaPlayer mp;
char[] currentNotes;
int noteIndex;
// Create the mp in onCreate and register your onCompletion callback

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    EditText keyInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.key);
    String notes = keyInput.getText().toString();
    currentNotes = notes.toCharArray();
    noteIndex = 0;
    mp.setDataSource(getNoteResource(currentNotes[0]));
    mp.start();
}

// Convert tone values into 
public int getNoteResource(char tone) {…}

@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
    if(++noteIndex < currentNotes.length) {
        mp.setDataSource(getNoteResource(currentNotes[noteIndex]));
        mp.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please write this type of answers in comments.

Comment: I'm new to android studio. I don't know which context I should do this in?

Comment: @DavidDoyle, If your media player is in another class use intent to send char array of this class to another one.

Comment: @DavidDoyle Why do you need a char array anyways? What do you want to do with the user input?

Comment: @KeksArmee I want to create a char array to link a mediaplayer class to each character. I don't know if it will work, but I want to give it a shot.

Comment: @DavidDoyle I updated it. This code would play note by note. You need raw resource ids for every note. Also it's a very crude implementation that would probably crash the app every time the user enters invalid notes.

Comment: @KeksArmee I wanted to create an on click listener so it played it all on a button click.